# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0

Tags: gradle

I am developing an app using react-native and I am getting the error that depreceated gradle features were used making it in compatible with **gradle 7.0** but I don't have **gradle 7.0** I am using **gradle 6.0.1**. Can anyone suggest why is that.
Below is the image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a deprecation warning giving you a heads-up that once you DO UPGRADE to 7.0 your build will stop working. In other words: you are using deprecated Gradle features which are scheduled for removal in v7.0 (next major version).

To remove the warning run your task with `--warning-mode=all` CLI parameter to see what those features are and refactor your build.gradle to eliminate usages of these features.

Comment: what do you mean by refactoring the build gradle

Comment: Change it so that it does not use the deprecated features.